# How does Dialogflow choose language after receiving a request by Telegram bot?

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I have 2 languages in a Dialogflow agent filled with intents and entities. English is chosen as a default language. How is my other language supposed to work? I dont understand why requests in another language marked as "en" in training log. Because of that, Dialogflow doesn't understand that it should compare requests with intents from another language.

I don't have any backend between telegram bot and Dialogflow - pure telegram integration through Dialogflow out of the box.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same problem, DF just goes to Default Fallback for anything in 2nd language.

Comment: @macasas nope. The only way I found - is to insert a middleware between a user request and DF for finding and setting a language before making a request to DF API.